# How to modify SpannableString to string below icon?

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, spannablestring, android-icons

Currently I have a spannableString like this, the icon is at the left of the title string. The problem is, is there any way to make the icon above the string , while the icon is align center?

Sample like this:

```
    []  <==== This is the icon
 TitleTest  <=== This is the title
   ABCD
```

Thanks

Here is my code attempted:

```
   Drawable image = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    image.setBounds(0, 0, image.getIntrinsicWidth(), image.getIntrinsicHeight());
    // Replace blank spaces with image icon
    SpannableString sb = new SpannableString("   " + tabTitles[position]);
    ImageSpan imageSpan = new ImageSpan(image, ImageSpan.ALIGN_BASELINE);
    sb.setSpan(imageSpan, 0, 1, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    return sb;
```

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 2):

I was looking at https://guides.codepath.com/android/Google-Play-Style-Tabs-using-TabLayout today and had the same question. Adding a newline to the SpannableString worked for me, so the following modification will do the trick:

```
SpannableString sb = new SpannableString(" \n" + tabTitles[position]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the three views (ImageView for icon and 2 `TextView`s) in a vertical `LinearLayout` and use the `android:layout_gravity` property in XML to centre the views in the `LinearLayout`. Additionally set the `android:gravity` property on the `TextView`s to be "center" to centre the text within the `TextView`.

If you don't want to use XML (which seems to be the case) layout_gravity can be set using the `LinearLayout.LayoutParams` constructor with parameters for width, height AND GRAVITY. Text alignment can be done using `mTextView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);`

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `drawableTop` attribute for this.

```
<TextView
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/my_drawable"/>
```

Or from code:

```
myTextView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(
        0, R.drawable.my_drawable, 0, 0);
```